# Git central repository for code management

Tags: bitbucket

I have an account in https://bitbucket.org for my project code management. I would like to choose my project belongs to git version control.I already worked with SVN version control. When I exploring the tutorial of creating a git repository I found that, creating a central repository and cloning the project into my local repository/local machine.

My doubt is that when I created my Bitbucket account, I got to home screen, and code commits options. This central repository location is owned by Bitbucket team. Actual space belongs to git teams. Can I create the same central repository in my personal On-Premise server? I need to create that central location within my remote machine instead of Bitbucket space.

I don't know my thinking direction is true or not. I need to know is this possible or not. How can I solve this space customization doubt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can access your remote machine remotely yes. This example is if you can have `ssh` with your remote, I do not know how to do it with `http` or any other protocol.

To do so, create a git repository in your remote host (get in your server using ssh and then create a git repository using `git init --bare`, note that most times if your local repo is called `my_repo`your server one would be called `my_repo.git`). Then, in your local computer, create another repository. In the local repository you can add the remote origin either using http or ssh (I only have tested in my own remotes using ssh). To add your remote origini run:

```
git remote add origin user@remote_server:pat/to/remote/repository.git
```

then, you can git `pull` and `push` between the local and remote repository (note that first you need to push to origin with `git push origin master`).

[Here](https://git-scm.com/book/it/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server) you have a complete example on how to do it.

Comment: why would "If you can access your remote machine via ssh yes" be a limiting factor? you add remotes with paths if ssh isn't viable option

Comment: You are completly right. I've edited my comment so I make clear it can be done using `http`as well but I do not know how to configure it.